# How to lock the place of buttons in Excel without breaking my macro

Tags: vba, excel

How to lock command buttons in place so you can't move them anymore in your worksheet?  If I lock my worksheet, then my macro does not work.

Comment: can you provide more clarity on exactly what you to lock? you want to lock the code in the worksheet module? or lock a button on a sheet that runs a macro? or something else?

Comment: You mean like moving the macros in your VBA project or moving the buttons that have been assigned macros?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You have to lock the sheet.
Review Tab --> Protect Sheet.  Also make sure that the button has the locked button checked when you right click on the button, click format shape or format control, then go to properties or protection depending on what type of button you are using.  You also might have to adjust your macro code by unprotecting the sheet first, running the macro code, and then reprotecting the sheet at the end of the code.Use something like the below:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Unprotect Password:="password"
[Macro code here]
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingRows:=True, Password:="password"
```

Comment: the problem with this that i can't use them anymore

Comment: You can still click on buttons when the sheet is locked.

Comment: You can also select all cells in that sheet, and mark as unprotected, so that when the sheet is protected, the only thing 'locked' is the button itself.

Comment: he keep saying you can't do that and then he shows the macro in Error mode

Comment: Oh you will probably need to adjust your macro code.  Unlock the workbook run the macro code and then reprotect the workbook at the end of the code. I edited my answer.